# Looking for a verb that means "to fashion letters and words on paper with skill"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single verb that describes what a good calligrapher does.  Something like, "He *calligraphed* the invitations quite nicely."  Is there such a word?

Comment: Have you tried looking up _calligraph_ in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes.  Didn't show up.

Comment: You need a better dictionary, then. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/calligraph) has it, for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a verb that means to write in calligraphy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256808/is-there-a-verb-that-means-to-write-in-calligraphy)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet To be fair, I think you just got lucky to look in just the right one for this. It's not in most of the dictionaries The Free Dictionary consults, aside from wordnet and that includes Random House Webter's College dictionary, the American Heritage Dictionary and Collins Unabridged (which boasts the highest advertised word count). Those are some pretty fine dictionaries to lack it in my opinion, if somebody chose to consult a printed source, so this seems to be a part of the extended vocabulary of English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the verb **to calligraph** works nicely.  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/calligraph)

> v write beautifully and ornamentally

Your sentence is correct, as it is here in another example:

> May 10, 1985… I **calligraphed** a Mother's Day card, put a $20 bill in it
>   along with a box of pretty soap for the big day. Isaacson, Lauren Ann

Etymonline dates its 1st use as 1610.  [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/calligraphy#etymonline_v_605)